# Finding the coefficient using the multinomial theorem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multinomial-coefficients

Set $F := F (X, Y, Z) = (X^2 + 3Y − Z^2)^8$. Determine the coefficients with which the
following terms appear in $F$.

1. $X^4 Y^2 Z^2.$
2. $X^{10} Y^2 Z^2$.

I would know how to find the coefficient if it was just $(X^2+Y-Z^2)^8$. It is the coefficient of the $y$ term that is making me stuck. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

The way I think about it is this.  Instead of thinking about the coefficient of $Y$, think about the coefficient of $(3Y)$.  Similarly think about the coefficient of $(-Z^2)$ instead of the coefficient of $Z$,
and the coefficient of $(X^2)$ instead of the coefficient of $X$.
So you write
$$
(X^2 + 3Y - Z^2)^8 = ((X^2) + (3Y) + (-Z^2))^8
$$
Now for the first question, you need the coefficient of
$$
X^4 Y^2 Z^2
$$
But what that really means is you need to find the term with $(X^2)^2 (3Y)^2 (-Z^2)^1$.
But there is no such coefficient.  Then for the next one, you need the coefficient of
$$
X^{10} Y^2 Z^2
$$
But what this really means is you need to find the term with
$(X^2)^5 (3Y)^2 (-Z^2)^1$.
So first, find the coefficient of $a^5 b^2 c$ in $(a + b + c)^8$.
Then just write $a = (X^2)$, $b = (3Y)$, and $c = (-Z^2)$,
and find what the new coefficient is.
**Hint:** the new coefficient will just be multiplied by some factors of 3 (from $b$) and -1 (from $c$).