# Quickest way to find coefficient of trinomial

Tags: multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

How can I find the coefficient of $a^3b^2$ in the expansion of:

$$ (a+b+3)^5 $$

What is the quickest way to do this without doing the whole expansion?

> [Answer:](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+(a%2Bb%2B3)%5E5)
>  Coefficient of $a^3b^2$ is $10$ according to `WolframAlpha`

Comment: Do it like in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789435/finding-the-coefficient-using-the-multinomial-theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [multinomial theorem and coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

$$(a+b+3)^5 = \sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=5} \frac{5!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!}a^{k_1}b^{k_2}3^{k_3}$$

We're looking for $k_1=3, k_2=2, k_3=0$. The corresponding multinomial coefficient is

$$\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!} = \frac{5!}{3!2!0!} = \frac{120}{12}=10.$$

Note that $\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{2} =\frac{5!}{3!2!}\frac{5!}{5!0!} = \frac{5!}{3!2!0!}$ as in uniquesolution's answer.

Comment: Each term goes as $a^{k_1}b^{k_2}3^{k_3}$. In order to equal $a^3b^2$ we need $3^{k_3}=3^0=1$. Note, we require $k_1+k_2+k_3=5$.

Comment: So, for example, is  $166,320$ the coefficient of $x^4y^5$ in the expansion of $(x+y+2)^{12}$? because [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+(x%2By%2B2)%5E12) it shows $221,760$

Comment: It's different in that case, but we follow the same principle. Note that we need $x^{k_1}y^{k_2}2^{k_3}$ where $k_1+k_2+k_3=12$. We already have $k_1=4$ and $k_2=5$, so it must be that $k_3=3$. Then the term is $\frac{12!}{5!4!3!}x^{4}y^{5}2^{3} = 221760x^{4}y^{5}$. The powers of $2$ have been absorbed into the coefficient. In the original problem, we had $3^0=1$, so this issue didn't arise.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$(a+b+3)^5 = (a+b+3)(a+b+3)(a+b+3)(a+b+3)(a+b+3)$$
You want to choose $3$ $a$'s and two $b$'s. You have ${5 \choose 3}=10$ ways to choose the $a$'s, and then you must choose $b$'s from the other two parentheses, so you have $10$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the quickest way, but:

$$(a+b+3)^5=((a+b)+3)^5$$

which produces powers of $a+b$, so the multinomial coefficient is the binomial coefficient on the one free power of $a+b$, which is the only one that contains $a^3b^2$, and is $\binom{5}{2}=10$